# Files in directory sort by fileName ascending

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I am having a list of files from a directory and I want to sort it out by filename.

This is the main code:

```
var localPath = this.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Img/" + type + "/");
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(localPath);
isDirectory = directory.Exists;

if (isDirectory)
{
    foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        Picture picture = new Picture();

        picture.ImagePath = path;
        picture.CreationDate = f.CreationTime;
        picture.FileName = f.Name;
        listPictures.Add(picture);
    }
}
```

here is the class Picture where all the files are stored:

```
public class Picture
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

How do you do to sort a files list by order of FileName?

Comment: why downvotes? The question seems legitimate to me

Comment: @SteveB: I think due total simplicity of the question which can be googled or even searched over SO itself, there will be tons of answers!

Comment: this has been [debated on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers). Not sure if this question falls into acceptable or non acceptable question.

Comment: You probably don't need to create your own class Picture, why not just use the built-in object FileInfo, which already has your desired attributes; rename upon usage, e.g. `var picture = new FileInfo();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change your for loop :

```
foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles().OrderBy(fi=>fi.FileName))
{

}
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the whole loop using this code :

```
var sortedFiles = from fi in directory.GetFiles()
                  order by fi.FileName
                  select new Picture { ImagePath = path, CreationDate = f.CreationTime, FileName = f.FileName };

listPictures.AddRange(sortedFiles);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listPictures = listPictures.OrderBy(x => x.FileName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda expression and/or extension methods. For example:

```
listPictures.OrderBy(p => p.FileName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx) performs lazy loading and can be more efficient for larger directories, so:

```
dir.EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(f => f.FileName))
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but since you're calling `OrderBy`, I believe Linq will have to process the whole collection before returning the first elements. Therefore, lazy loading won't have any impact.

Comment: Note that [`Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) will be more efficient if only the `FileName` is used.

Comment: @KooKiz: Yes, but using `EnumerateFiles` has the advantage that you can change the query to: `dir.EnumerateFiles().Where(f=>f.CreationTime>=DateTime.Now.AddAyears(-1)).OrderBy(f=>f.FileName)` without remembering to use now `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`. So why not using it from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ from the beginning:

```
var files = from f in directory.EnumerateFiles()
    let pic = new Picture(){
        ImagePath = path;
        CreationDate = f.CreationTime;
        FileName = f.Name;
    }
    orderby pic.FileName
    select pic;
```

Note that [`Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) will be more efficient if only the `FileName` is used.