# C# Extract the most recent zipped file only

Tags: c#

Finally got my code working fine, but I need to extract the most recent zipped file within the directory.

Really not sure how to go about this, can someone please point me in the correct direction, was thinking of using modified date and time, please see my code below...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;


namespace unZipMe
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            DirectoryInfo file = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract");


            if(file.Exists)
            {
                file.Delete(true);
            }

            string myDir = (@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract");


            bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(myDir);

            if (!exists)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myDir);
            }



            //provide the folder to be zipped
            //string folderToZip = @"c:\Temp\ZipSample";

            //provide the path and name for the zip file to create
            string zipFile = @"c:\Temp\ZipSampleOutput\MyZippedDocuments.zip";

            //call the ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory() method
            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderToZip, zipFile, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);

            //specif the directory to which to extract the zip file


            string extractFolder = @"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract\";

            //call the ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() method
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, extractFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Post your attempts at solving this. (2) Define "recent". Last created? Last added to the folder? Sorted by a timestamp in the name, rather than the file info? If based on filename, an example wouldn't go amiss here. (3) `@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract\"` is copy/pasted in code several times. Use a variable.

Comment: Look at ZipArchive and ZipArchiveEntry, they have the timestamps you probably need

Comment: Why do you check if the **c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract**  directory exist twice?

Comment: You're just asking about sorting, array has a sort method, or you can sort using linq very easily.  You seem to have a grasp on the rest. Here's an old answer that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155131/files-in-directory-sort-by-filename-ascending